# Is the superuser site the place for troubleshooting?

Tags: discussion

I'm having problems with VirtualBox, and I want to know if SuperUser is the right place to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that would be the proper site to ask questions about that.

From the SuperUser FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> … and it is not about videogames or consoles, then you're in the right place to ask your question!

https://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

Per the [/faq](https://superuser.com/faq) :

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> … and it is *not* about videogames or consoles, then you're in the right place to ask your question!

so, yes!

Comment: Thanks!

 Ironically, I just solved the issue. ¬¬